# Does this equation have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was considering some number theory problems which inspired me to write the following conjecture, which bears some resemblance to the Catalan problem, but is in fact different:

Fix two distinct sequences of primes $p_{1}, ..., p_{n}$ and $q_{1}, ..., q_{m}$. Do there exist infinitely many sequences of naturals $a_{1}, ..., a_{n}$, $b_{1}, ..., b_{m}$ such that:

$p_{1}^{a_{1}} ... p_{n}^{a_{n}} - q_{1}^{b_{1}} ... q_{m}^{b_{m}} = 1$?

Comment: With one factor each side, do you know what happens with $p=3$ and $q=2$?

Comment: It only has one solution in that case

Comment: I'm interested in cases where at least one of $n, m$ is bigger than 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thue proved (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation) that the equation
$$A \cdot X^k - B \cdot Y^k = 1$$
(for fixed $A$, $B$, and $k$) has only finitely many integral solutions if $k \ge 3$.

Fix two sets of primes $p_i$ and $q_j$. Your equations give integral solutions to a finite number of Thue equations, and thus there can be at most finitely
many solutions.

For example (to be very explicit about the construction), any solution to $2^a 3^b - 5^c 7^c = 1$ yields a solution
to 
$$A x^3 - B y^3 = 1$$
 with $A \in \{1,2,4,3,6,12,9,18,36\}$ and 
$B \in \{1,5,25,7,35,175,49,245,1225\}$.

More generally, this problem falls under the broader class of problems
known as $S$-unit equations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-unit), which are well studied.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional on the [abc conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), the answer is no. We have $1 + \prod q_i^{b_i} = \prod p_i^{a_i}$ and the abc conjecture implies that 
$$\prod p_i^{a_i} \le (\prod p_i \prod q_i)^2$$

for all but finitely many choices of the $a_i$ and $b_i$. But this condition itself can only hold for finitely many choices of the $a_i$.